# How to implemet 1D convolution in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, convolution

Is there any way to implement convolution of 1D signal in OpenCV?

As I can see there is only filter2D, but I'm looking for something like Matlab's convn.

Comment: there are separable 1d filters: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga910e29ff7d7b105057d1625a4bf6318d

Comment: Or you can do it yourself with a couple of for loops.

Comment: @berak as I understand this applies two 1D filters to 2D Mat, but I need to apply 1d filter to 1d signal(for example row of 2D Mat).

Answer (score 2):

For 1-D convolutions, you might want to look at np.convolve.

See here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html

Python OpenCV programs that need a 1-D convolution can use it readily.

Comment: Isn't op asking about c++?

Comment: C++ is not even mentioned in the question . . . It has only been tagged with C++ . . . A tag I didn't see. I will pay more attention to those tags next time :-) . . . I ran into this question while searching in general. I will let you and others evaluate the usefulness of approach suggested. I'm not married to it.

Comment: A reasonable answer for C++ seems to have been given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518989/how-to-perform-1-dimensional-valid-convolution

Answer (score 2):

You can always view a 1D vector as a 2D mat, and thus simply calling the opencv build-it functions resolves the problem.

Below is a snippet that I use to smooth an image histogram.

```
# Inputs: 
#     gray = a gray scale image
#     smoothing_nbins = int, the width of 1D filter
# Outputs:
#     hist_sm = the smoothed image histogram

hist = cv2.calcHist([gray],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
hist_sm = cv2.blur(hist, (1, smoothing_nbins))
```

As you can see, the only trick you need here is to set one filter dimension to 1.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you use convolve2D with just the 1D matrix, it still works. But depending on your specific work, it may not.