# Corrupt heap after allocating vector on esp32

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I am trying to compute optical flow (lucas kanade - based) on an esp32-cam. 
I tried to save memory by operating on 2 small buffer of array only. I still have an error corrupt heap:

> test0
>
> bfore allocate out conv
>
> after allocate out conv
>
> bfore allocate out conv
>
> after allocate out conv
>
> bfore allocate out conv
>
> after allocate out conv
>
> bfore allocate out conv
>
> CORRUPT HEAP: multi_heap.c:432 detected at 0x3fff7114 abort() was
>   called at PC 0x40090a7f on core 0

Here is my code composed of 1D convolution and transpose to perform separate equivalent 2D convolution:

```
    template<typename T>
    void
    conv(uint8_t *in, const std::vector<T> &g, const int nf) {
        //int const nf = f.size();
        int const ng = g.size();
        int const n  = nf + ng - 1;
        uint8_t *f = in;
        Serial.println("bfore allocate out conv");
        std::vector<T> out(n, T()); // memory leak CORRUPT HEAP
        Serial.println("after allocate out conv");  
        for(auto i(0); i < n; ++i) {
            int const jmn = (i >= ng - 1)? i - (ng - 1) : 0;
            int const jmx = (i <  nf - 1)? i            : nf - 1;
            for(auto j(jmn); j <= jmx; ++j) {
                out[i] += (f[j] * g[i - j]);
            }
        }
        out.erase(out.begin(), out.begin() + ng / 2 + 1);

        // Rescale to 0..255
        auto max = *std::max_element(out.begin(), out.end());
        auto min = *std::min_element(out.begin(), out.end());
        float x;
        for(auto v : out) {
            x = (v - min) * 255.0 / max;
            *(f++) = (uint8_t)x;
        }
        std::vector<T>().swap(out);
    }

    void transpose(uint8_t *f, int w, int h) {
        for(auto i(0); i < h; ++i) 
            for(auto j(0); j < w; ++j) 
                std::swap(f[w * i + j], f[w * j + i]);
    }

    void LK_optical_flow(uint8_t *src1, uint8_t *src2, uint8_t *output, int w, int h)
    {

        Serial.println("test0");

        std::vector<float> Kernel_Dy = {1, 2, 1};
        std::vector<float> Kernel_Dx = {-1, 0, 1};
        std::vector<float> Kernel_Dt = {1/3.0, 1/3.0, 1/3.0};

        uint8_t *fx = src1;
        uint8_t *fy = new uint8_t[w * h];
        uint8_t *ft = src2;

        memcpy(fy, fx, w * h * sizeof(uint8_t));

        // Sobel Dx
        conv(fx, Kernel_Dx, w*h);
        transpose(fx, w, h);
        conv(fx, Kernel_Dy, w*h);
        transpose(fx, w, h);    
        // Sobel Dy
        conv(fy, Kernel_Dy, w*h);
        transpose(fy, w, h);
        conv(fy, Kernel_Dx, w*h);  // memory leak
        transpose(fy, w, h);    
        // Dt
        //conv(src2, Kernel_Dt, w*h);
    ...
    }
```

Apparently the leaks come from the second buffer I allocated pointed by `fy` during the second call of `conv(fy, ...)` when it allocate out as vector.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not erase part of array, i.e. ```out.erase(out.begin(), out.begin() + ng / 2 + 1);``` - it can cause performance degradation and memory fragmentation - memory will be freed when you leave function anyway. Your algorithm can work just fine without this erase. And this ```std::vector<T>().swap(out);``` baffles me as well - It serves no purpose as far as I can see. And esp32 has only 512kb of RAM on board. Is it enough for your purpose? - Please extend your question and provide some info regarding values of  ```w``` and ```h```.

Comment: I see a problem in `transpose` that will access and write to out-of-bounds memory if `w` and `h` are not equal (i.e., if your not working with square matrices).

Comment: @Maxim Sagaydachny : it's a [full convolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518989/how-to-perform-1-dimensional-valid-convolution) so i remove the edge to keep the size same as input image. Yes I can remove the swap but it doesn't matter it's the right way to free a vector. w is 96 and h about half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `w` and `h` not being the same, `transpose` will access and write to out-of-bounds memory.

From your comment, you have `w` at 96 and `h` at about 48.  The second parameter to `swap` in `transpose` will access up to `f[w * (w - 1) + h * (h - 1)]` which is past the `w * h` elements you've allocated.  This will change memory that hasn't been allocated, and in your case is corrupting the data your library uses to keep track of allocated memory (which is only detected during an allocation of free, and may not get detected right away).

The solution involves rewriting `transpose` to properly transpose a rectangular matrix.  (This involves swapping `w` and `h` for the returned matrix.)

Comment: Thank you. I know why I made this mistake before that f was a vector so dynamically allocated and transpose worked fine.